# How would I go about defining the dimensions of an <img> without knowing what the image is going to be

Tags: html, image, user-profile

I'm trying to make a profile picture thumbnail where the image is different for each user. I want to define the dimensions in which the image must conform to. Since the image is going to be different for each user, how would I go about writing the HTML without knowing what the file name of the image is going to be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Option A: just don't define the size; `<img>` will be automatically sized and the document reflowed when the image loads. Not pretty, but best you can do if you really have no idea what the sizes will be.
- Option B: enter either the height or the width; let the browser scale the other dimension upon load. This is nice if you can fit a fixed height or width in your layout.
- Option C: use CSS to specify max width and max height. The image will be scaled to be inside that rectangle. This is nice.
- Option D: specify the height and width in CSS. If you have images of different size, they will be stretched, which will look awful.
- Option E: same as D, but crop and/or resize the thumbnails so that you know the size in advance. Best option if you can do it.

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS.

Give the image a class and write a CSS declaration like this:

`<img class="profilepic" src="path/to/image" />`

```
.profilepic {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
}
```

You can also just put the styles inline if you wish.

`<img style="width:100px;height:100px;" src="path/to/image" />`